# Bootstrap Jquery Button Ajax Value

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have updated this question as the context in which I  explained was wrong.

Let me explain what I would like to do, I have a table row with a button on.  When the user presses the button it does an ajax call to a web service and on success I would like to change the text on the button to something else.

I have tried saving the value of this before the ajax call and on success pass in  this as a variable and try to change button text.

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tonymaloney1971/xgq2uumv/1/

The fiddle is just the idea of what I need to do, it doesn't run.

Here is the code  I have tried

```
$('#SendEmail').on('click', function () {  
 //save this to var
 var thisContext = this;

 sendEmail(bookingID, function (thisContext) {
     $(thisContext).val("hello");     
});


 function sendEmail(id, onWebServiceSuccess) {
     //var data = JSON.stringify({ 'id': id });

     //webService.jsonPOST("ResendEmail", data, onWebServiceSuccess, onWebServiceFailed);
     return true;
 };
```

Thanks

Comment: DO you want to change the button text which is clicked ??

Comment: `ReferenceError: tableRow is not defined`. Open your browser console (using F12) and check if there are any js error; they might help you find the bug

Comment: Hi, that was an incorrect fiddle, try http://jsfiddle.net/qup186ue/2/

Comment: do you need this http://jsfiddle.net/qup186ue/3/

Answer (score 1):

Change the text using the `.text()` property on its click

```js
$('#SendEmail').on('click', function () {   
      $(this).text("hello");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="SendEmail">Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $('#SendEmail').on('click', function () {   
      $(this).val("hello");
  });
```